# how to repeat hyperparameter tuning (alpha and/or lambda) of glmnet in mlr3

Tags: r, r-caret, mlr3

I would like to repeat the hyperparameter tuning (`alpha` and/or `lambda`) of `glmnet` in `mlr3` to [avoid variability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079660/extract-the-coefficients-for-the-best-tuning-parameters-of-a-glmnet-model-in-car) in smaller data sets

In `caret`, I could do this with `"repeatedcv"`

Since I really like the `mlr3` family packages I would like to use them for my analysis. However, I am not sure about the correct way how to do this step in `mlr3`

Example data

```r
#library
library(caret)
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlbench)

# get example data
data(PimaIndiansDiabetes, package="mlbench")
data <- PimaIndiansDiabetes

# get small training data
train.data <- data[1:60,]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**`caret` approach (tuning `alpha` and `lambda`) using `"cv"` and `"repeatedcv"`**

```
trControlCv <- trainControl("cv",
             number = 5,
             classProbs = TRUE,
             savePredictions = TRUE,
             summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

# use "repeatedcv" to avoid variability in smaller data sets
trControlRCv <- trainControl("repeatedcv",
             number = 5,
             repeats= 20,
             classProbs = TRUE,
             savePredictions = TRUE,
             summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

# train and extract coefficients with "cv" and different set.seed
set.seed(2323)
model <- train(
  diabetes ~., data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trControlCv,
  tuneLength = 10,
  metric="ROC"
)

coef(model$finalModel, model$finalModel$lambdaOpt) -> coef1

set.seed(23)
model <- train(
  diabetes ~., data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trControlCv,
  tuneLength = 10,
  metric="ROC"
)

coef(model$finalModel, model$finalModel$lambdaOpt) -> coef2


# train and extract coefficients with "repeatedcv" and different set.seed
set.seed(13)

model <- train(
  diabetes ~., data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trControlRCv,
  tuneLength = 10,
  metric="ROC"
)

coef(model$finalModel, model$finalModel$lambdaOpt) -> coef3


set.seed(55)
model <- train(
  diabetes ~., data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trControlRCv,
  tuneLength = 10,
  metric="ROC"
)

coef(model$finalModel, model$finalModel$lambdaOpt) -> coef4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**Demonstrate different coefficients with cross-validation and same coefficients with repeated cross-validation**

```
# with "cv" I get different coefficients
identical(coef1, coef2)
#> [1] FALSE

# with "repeatedcv" I get the same coefficients
identical(coef3,coef4)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

FIRST `mlr3` approach using `cv.glmnet` (does internally tune `lambda`)

```
# create elastic net regression
glmnet_lrn = lrn("classif.cv_glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

# define train task
train.task <- TaskClassif$new("train.data", train.data, target = "diabetes")

# create learner 
learner = as_learner(glmnet_lrn)

# train the learner with different set.seed
set.seed(2323)
learner$train(train.task)
coef(learner$model, s = "lambda.min") -> coef1

set.seed(23)
learner$train(train.task)
coef(learner$model, s = "lambda.min") -> coef2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**Demonstrate different coefficients with cross-validation**

```
# compare coefficients
coef1
#> 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                        1
#> (Intercept) -3.323460895
#> age          0.005065928
#> glucose      0.019727881
#> insulin      .          
#> mass         .          
#> pedigree     .          
#> pregnant     0.001290570
#> pressure     .          
#> triceps      0.020529162
coef2
#> 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>                        1
#> (Intercept) -3.146190752
#> age          0.003840963
#> glucose      0.019015433
#> insulin      .          
#> mass         .          
#> pedigree     .          
#> pregnant     .          
#> pressure     .          
#> triceps      0.018841557
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

### **Update 1: the progress I made**

According to the comment below and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66644375/two-level-stacked-learner-enseble-model-combining-elastic-net-and-logistic-reg/66665277?noredirect=1#comment117900429_66665277) I could use `rsmp` and
`AutoTuner`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800689/tuning-glmnet-using-mlr3) suggests not to tune `cv.glmnet` but `glmnet` (which was not available in ml3 at that time)

**SECOND `mlr3` approach using `glmnet` (repeats the tuning of `alpha` and `lambda`)**

```
# define train task
train.task <- TaskClassif$new("train.data", train.data, target = "diabetes")

# create elastic net regression
glmnet_lrn = lrn("classif.glmnet", predict_type = "prob")

# turn to learner
learner = as_learner(glmnet_lrn)

# make search space
search_space = ps(
  alpha = p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 1),
  s = p_dbl(lower = 1, upper = 1)
)

# set terminator
terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 20)

#set tuner
tuner = tnr("grid_search", resolution = 3)

# tune the learner
at = AutoTuner$new(
  learner = learner,
  rsmp("repeated_cv"),
  measure = msr("classif.ce"),
  search_space = search_space,
  terminator = terminator,
  tuner=tuner)

at
#> <AutoTuner:classif.glmnet.tuned>
#> * Model: -
#> * Parameters: list()
#> * Packages: glmnet
#> * Predict Type: prob
#> * Feature types: logical, integer, numeric
#> * Properties: multiclass, twoclass, weights
```

### Open Question

How can I demonstrate that my second approach is valid and that I get same or similar coefficients with different seeds? ie. how can I extract the coefficients for the final model of the `AutoTuner`

```
set.seed(23)
at$train(train.task) -> tune1

set.seed(2323) 
at$train(train.task) -> tune2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You can do the same thing in mlr3, see https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/resampling.html

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thank you for your comment. I adjusted my question accordingly.

Comment: I am not really sure what your question is here or if it has been answered already - please try to ask concise and short questions in the future (a reprex is great though!). You can also answer your own questions and ask a new one if in doubt. Answering your questions: I've answered the questions how to tune `glmnet` with the old `mlr` [here]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50995525/nested-resampling-lasso-regr-cvglment-using-mlr/51144302#51144302). Porting it to `mlr3` should not be that hard. I do not have time right now though. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment. I tried to more concisely state the progress I made (due to comments) and the question's open point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeated hyperparameter tuning (alpha and lambda) of `glmnet` can be done using **the SECOND `mlr3` approach** as stated above.
The coefficients can be extracted with `stats::coef` and the stored values in the `AutoTuner`

```
coef(tune1$model$learner$model, alpha=tune1$tuning_result$alpha,s=tune1$tuning_result$s)
# 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 1
# (Intercept) -1.6359082102
# age          0.0075541841
# glucose      0.0044351365
# insulin      0.0005821515
# mass         0.0077104934
# pedigree     0.0911233031
# pregnant     0.0164721202
# pressure     0.0007055435
# triceps      0.0056942014
coef(tune2$model$learner$model, alpha=tune2$tuning_result$alpha,s=tune2$tuning_result$s)
# 9 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# 1
# (Intercept) -1.6359082102
# age          0.0075541841
# glucose      0.0044351365
# insulin      0.0005821515
# mass         0.0077104934
# pedigree     0.0911233031
# pregnant     0.0164721202
# pressure     0.0007055435
# triceps      0.0056942014
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are specifying s = 1 ( s = p_dbl(lower = 1, upper = 1) ). You are only considering one lambda value this way. Shouldn't this either be tuned over, or determined from cv.glmnet?

You and I may be trying to solve similar problems!

Comment: For more info, I like the answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77546/how-to-interpret-glmnet/77549